# Checking for overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features

Since updating QGIS from version 3.20.2 to 3.24.0 I no longer have the same `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity` options.

This used to allow me to specify how much (area) polygon slivers could overlap. It would put the overlaps into a new layer. How do I get that functionality back?

Meanwhile I have managed to pick up some overlaps using https://mapshaper.org/.

Comment: The tool is still there. Is your Processing Toolbox activated in the Manage and Install Plugins dialog?

Comment: I've just looked at *plugins* and whatever I enabled or updated there has added "**Check Geometries**" into the menu. That is the dialog that I was missing.